# Fullcalendar not loading correct when calendar view is not in focus

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, bootstrap-tabs

I have created a pen here:

https://codepen.io/jokkis0/pen/daNqZy

```
fullcalendar('refetchEvents') not working
```

I have a bootstrap tab where one showing the calendar, and the other is showing a datatable. 
On datatable I have a delete button on each event, when I delete and reloads the calendar, the calendar is not being populated. If I add a button on the tab where the calendar is, that rerender the calendar, the calendar will show as expected. I can see that the "TR" rows on the reources are being set as "height=0", so I think the Javascript is trying to set a height dynamicly, but it seems it will fail when the calendar view is hidden.

Do you have any suggestion to handle this?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I have now updated my codepen. If you open codepen, and click on claendar tab, then click refresh, so the calendar will show correctly, and then click back on "list". Try to delete one item. And then click back on "calendar". Then you will see that calendar is not loading right.

Comment: your datatable appears to be empty so it's hard to use your codepen to reproduce the issue

Comment: The datatable is nothing to do with it. If you look at codepen. The calendar loads when the view is in focus but not when the calendar tab not selected

Comment: In the question you specifically state that the problem occurs when you delete something from the table and then try to reload the calendar events. So if you want us to solve that we'll need some data in the table. If the problem is something different then please re-write the question to be clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson - thanks for your feedback. 
I have now updated my codepen. If you open codepen, and click on claendar tab, then click refresh, so the calendar will show correctly, and then click back on "list". Try to delete one item. And then click back on "calendar". Then you will see that calendar is not loading right.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think the bootstrap tabs are the issue here. If you simply remove the tabs then there's no problem at all. I would suspect that maybe moving away from the tab causes everything within it to be removed from the DOM temporarily, meaning fullCalendar can't properly find itself in order to re-draw, or that, at the very least, being invisible messes up the sizes of things, so fullCalendar's calculations go wrong when it tries to re-draw.

Comment: I think you need to hook into the event which occurs when you move between tabs, and when opening the calendar tab, force fullCalendar to do either a "refetchEvents" or maybe even a full ["render"](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/render) at that moment so that the calendar size is calculated correctly. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#events for hooking into the various events. I'd imagine "shown" is probably the one you want.

Comment: Thank for reply. I will try that 